# doGet(e) does not output the HTML file when the macro URL run from a consumer Gmail account

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a very strange problem that I couldn't be able to find the reason and solve it.

Under our Google Workspace account, I have created a Google Apps Script project and deployed it as a webapp. Basically the code is a simple doGet(e) which runs some simple code and then outputs a "Success" HTML page:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log("Webinar Webhook Triggered...");
  try {
    var webinar = e.parameter.Webinar_ID;
    var key = e.parameter.ID;
    var option = e.parameter.Option;
    Logger.log("Webinar ID > "+webinar);
    Logger.log("URL Row Key value > "+key);
    Logger.log("URL Row Option value > "+option);
    ...
    ... //some simple code here
    ...
    var HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'; style='width: 100%'><tr align='center'><td colspan='2'><img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=12iDQdcJ51JmuaIezQi8By9htqBZyCEiT'/></td></tr><tr align='center'><td colspan='2'><strong><h2>You have successfully enrolled to the upcoming GAS Webinar. Provided you think that you have unintentionally enrolled, you can unenroll by clicking the button below.</h2></strong></td></tr><tr align='center'><td colspan='2'><a href='https://script.google.com/macros/s/{script_id_here}/exec?Webinar_ID="+webinar+"&ID="+key+"&Option=unenroll' target='_blank'><img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1fDFNuJQUCw6XTeOGalACyUKuR2SHoNI2' width='150'/></a></td></tr></table>");
    return HTMLOutput
  } catch (e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("levent@able3ventures.com", "Webinar Webhook Error Occured!", 
      "\r\nMessage: " + e.message
      + "\r\nFile: " + e.fileName
      + "\r\nLine: " + e.lineNumber);
    e = (typeof e === 'string') ? new Error(e) : e;
    Logger.severe('%s: %s (line %s, file "%s"). Stack: "%s" . While processing %s.',e.name||'', 
               e.message||'', e.lineNumber||'', e.fileName||'', e.stack||'', processingMessage||'');
    throw e;
  }
}
```

The public URL of the script is inside an `<a href></a>` tag inside the email body. Basically when the user clicks the link, it should execute the doGet(e), execute some very simple code and then display the HTML output. Weird enough:

**1.)** Provided the mail recipient is a Google consumer account, when they execute the link the displayed page says that it can't open the file.

[image]

**2.)** Provided the user open the link with incognito mode, the HTML is shown successfully.

**3.)** Provided I create the same script and deploy project under my own personal consumer account rather than my workspace account, the link works and the HTML is rendered in a normal browser mode

I am looking to find out why this is happening and how I can fix this glitch.

Comment: Does the user executing the script have multiple accounts logged in?

Comment: @ale13 can you pls elaborate? When I execute the script with my consumer account, I have also logged in to my workspace account as well but the emails are different for sure. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: There is currently an open issue on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72798634) and it looks to be same situation you are describing. Can you confirm this?